# Change the color of span on hover

Tags: html, css

Hello guys here is my code to change color on hover. I can change the color of every object except one. -> SPAN_3

```
<li id="LI_2">
      <span id="SPAN_3"></span> <fade>example text</fade>
</li>


    .price-box:hover fade {
       color: #fff;

    }
    **.price-box:hover span {
       color: #ffffff !important;
    }**
```

I cannot change the color of span. How can I fix this ? I searched the web but couldn't find with a solution.

Comment: what is price-box? please share full code

Comment: can you post more code? it looks like you are missing the elements with the class .price-box

Comment: The span has no content. What colour do you think it will change to?

Comment: there is no text in side span so how u see color of text is changed or not

Comment: see some hover examples here http://jsfiddle.net/FPDCu/135/

Comment: I was using content: "asda"  in css to add content. Adding content in html solved my problem. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is your issue fixed code**

```
<li id="LI_2">
      <span id="SPAN_3"><fade>example text</fade></span> 
</li>


#SPAN_3:hover{color:red;}
#SPAN_3{color:#000;}
    .price-box:hover fade {
       color: #fff;

    }
    **.price-box:hover span {
       color: #ffffff !important;
    }**
```

Answer (score 2):

See its working

```css
li span{
  color:red;
}
li:hover span{
  color:black
}
```

```html
<li id="LI_2">
      <span id="SPAN_3">text for color change</span> <fade>example text</fade>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#SPAN_3{ color:#000;}
#LI_2{ color:#000;}
#LI_2:hover{ color:#ff0;}
#LI_2:hover{ color:#000;}
```

Comment: What kind of code is this? It looks like PHP comments :)