# How to change an html element text on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<span>` element which contains some text, namely `&times;`. How do I get this to change to a different symbol on hover. For example, to: `&infin;`?

```
<span class="change-text">&times;</span>
```

on mouse over, the visitor should see:

```
<span class="change-text">&infin;</span>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Using the span's `onmouseover` event should do the trick..

Comment: Can you post your code, and where it is you need help?

Comment: @AnisR. Yes, but how would I get the text to change?

Comment: @Stuart I don't have code yet. I just want to know how I can fix it...

Comment: @Paulie_D seems like you are giving a work around comment to "what have you tried?" SO results to the comment is **"If the author didn't show what was tried, why do you assume they tried anything? Either ask for a specific bit of information, suggest a specific improvement, or downvote and move on."** asking the OP to "google it" is hardly "specific". How about **"google mouse over events"**

Answer (score 6):

you can workaround this without using JavaScript.

in HTML code just make empty span:

`<span></span>`

in css add:

```
span::after {
    content: '\00d7';
}
span:hover::after {
    content: '\221E';
}
```

`\00d7`,`\221E` referring to symbol unicode.

```css
span:after { 
  content: '\00d7'
}
span:hover:after{
  content: '\221E'
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done entirely with CSS using pseudo elements, no JavaScript necessary.

```css
.icon:before {
    content: '×';
}

.icon:hover:before {
    content: '♥';
}
```

```html
<span class="icon"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

the onmouseover event is what you're looking for - don't forget to change it back when the mouse is removed.

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');
span.onmouseover = ()=>span.innerHTML = '&hearts;';
span.onmouseout = ()=>span.innerHTML = '&times;';
```

```html
<span>&times;</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to use Javascript's `mouseenter` and `mouseout` events, and attach them as event listeners to the span. Then, inside the event listener, change the node's text content.

Comment: You don't "have to"

Answer (score -1):

you can change the background color and something you want by event.
please refer this : [Change the color of span on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494787/change-the-color-of-span-on-hover)

Comment: This should be a comment or a vote to close as a duplicate. (I realize you can't do either yet but try to get your rep up by answering questions with actual answers, not one line comments with a link)

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestion @AdamBuchananSmith. I am just new to stack overflow. I will try to do improvement in this.

Comment: Keep your answer up, add some code and use links as references to back up your answer and if it answers the OP's question I'll come back and up vote it.